# Inheriting constructors in C++0x

Tags: c++, constructor, c++11

Lets say I have the following code in what we expect to become the next C++ standard:

```
int f(int x) 
{ 
  std::cout << x;
  return x * x; 
}

struct A
{
  A(int x) : m_x(x) {}
  int m_x;
};

struct B : A
{
  using A::A;
  B() : m_y(f(m_x)) {}
  int m_y;
};

int main()
{
  B(5);
}
```

Would this call the default constructor of B and print out 5 and set m_y = 25? Or will the default constructor of B not run, and leave m_y uninitialized?

And if the latter, what is the rationale behind not calling the B default constructor? It is quite clear that the A(int) B inherits only initialises A, and leaves B in an indeterminate state. Why would C++ choose undefined behaviour over simply calling the default constructor of B()? It largely defeats the purpose of the inheriting constructors feature.

**Edit:**

Perhaps this should be allowed:

```
using A::A : m_y(...) { std::cout << "constructing..." << std::endl; ...; }
```

Comment: m_y will be uninitialized, by using A::A, you will get something like this: B::B(int x) : A::m_x(x) {}. Or something:)

Comment: C++ actually chooses to compile you code with error as you don't provide default constructor for A. It is _not_ an undefined behaviour :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`using A::A;` implicitly declares `B(int)` in the derived class. That is it.

The rest of your program should not work as you expect. Because you're invoking `B(int)` with `B(5)`, and that leaves `m_y` uninitialized.

See this example from Bjarne Stroustrup's site:

```
struct B1 {
    B1(int) { }
};

struct D1 : B1 {
    using B1::B1; // implicitly declares D1(int)
    int x;
};

void test()
{
    D1 d(6);    // Oops: d.x is not initialized
    D1 e;       // error: D1 has no default constructor
}
```

http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#inheriting

Another example from the same link:

```
struct D1 : B1 {
        using B1::B1;   // implicitly declares D1(int)
        int x{0};   // note: x is initialized
    };

    void test()
    {
        D1 d(6);    // d.x is zero
    }
```

Comment: If D1 had a default constructor, would it be run when running the line "D1 d(6);"?

Comment: His example did not declare a default constructor for D1. Of course x is going to be not initialised, regardless of the "using B1:B1". My example however declares a default constructor.

Comment: @Clinton: Yes. But the default constructor is not invoked in your example. So it doesn't matter whether you define it or not, you invoke the implicitly declared constructor which is `B(int)` in your example.

Comment: @Nawaz: Why? What is the rationale behind not calling the default constructor? In no other instance in C++ can you create an object without calling its constructor.

Comment: @Clinton: Becase when you write `B(5)`, you pass an argument of type `int` to a constructor, and that constructor can only be `B(int)`, not `B()`. As I said, you do invoke constructor, but not the default constructor, rather the one which take one argument of type `int`.

Comment: @Nawaz: B(int) only constructs A, not B. Without calling a constructor of B, B is not valid. Why not simply call the default constructor of B()? I'm sure the standard writers are wiser than me, I just can't understand the rationale here though, which is probably my own failing.

Comment: @Clinton: `B(int)` is the constructor of `B`, not of `A`.

Comment: +1 @Clinton: It might be simpler to understand if you think on what the `using B1::B1` means for the compiler. The construct is translated (in this particular case) to `D1( int __x ) : B1(__x) {}`. Note that it does not mean *call the B1 constructor* but rather, *create a D1 constructor that will call the B1 constructor*. That constructor is not explicitly modifying the member `x` and because it is of type `int` that means that it is uninitialized. Unless, as per the last code snippet, it uses the initialization syntax in the declaration, in which case it will be correctly initialized.